# Show $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\int_X|f|^{n+1}d\mu}{\int_X|f|^nd\mu}=\|f\|_\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $\mu$ is a positive measure on $X$, $\mu(X)<\infty$, $f\in L^\infty(\mu)$, $\|f\|_\infty>0$, and
$$\alpha_n=\int_X|f|^nd\mu\quad(n=1,2,3,\ldots).$$
How to show that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\alpha_{n+1}}{\alpha_n}=\|f\|_\infty?$$

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried proving it for, e.g., sums of indicator functions $\chi_A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  Show

$$\|f\|_\infty \leqslant \liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{\alpha_{n+1}}{\alpha_n} \leqslant \limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\alpha_{n+1}}{\alpha_n}\leqslant \|f\|_\infty$$

**First Inequality**

Using Holder's Inequality with $1/p = n/(n+1)$ and $1/q = 1/(n+1)$:

$$\int_X|f|^{n}\,\mathrm{d}\mu \leqslant \left(\int_X|f|^{n+1}\,\mathrm{d}\mu\right)^{n/(n+1)}\left(\int_X\,\mathrm{d}\mu\right)^{1/(n+1)} = \left(\int_X|f|^{n+1}\,\mathrm{d}\mu\right)^{n/(n+1)}\left[\mu(X)\right]^{1/(n+1)}.$$

Then,

$$\frac{\int_X|f|^{n+1}\,\mathrm{d}\mu}{\int_X|f|^{n}\,\mathrm{d}\mu} \geqslant \left(\int_X|f|^{n+1}\,\mathrm{d}\mu\right)^{1/(n+1)}\left[\mu(X)\right]^{-1/(n+1)},$$

and

$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{\int_X|f|^{n+1}\,\mathrm{d}\mu}{\int_X|f|^{n}\,\mathrm{d}\mu} \geqslant \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int_X|f|^{n+1}\,\mathrm{d}\mu\right)^{1/(n+1)}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\mu(X)^{-1}\right]^{1/(n+1)}$$

Can you find the limits on the RHS?

Proving the second inequality is straightforward.